# graphene could not convert string to float in SerializerMutation

Tags: graphql, graphene-python, graphene-django

Is the `SerializerMutation` suppose to convert `ID!` from base64 to a pk? Is there some frontend/backend helper util to assist in conversion? I haven't been able to find anything specific.

Example create thing mutation:

```
class CreateThingMutation(SerializerMutation):
    @classmethod
    def get_serializer_kwargs(cls, root, info, **input):
        import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
        return None

    @classmethod
    def mutate_and_get_payload(cls, root, info, text, id):
        import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
        return None

    class Meta:
        serializer_class = ThingListViewSerializer
```

Example query:

```
  mutation TestCreate($input: CreateThingMutationInput!) {
    createThing(input: $input) {
      item {
          id
      }
    }
  }
```

Example `ID!`:

```
item.id === atob('VW5pdE5vZGU6MjA=') === "UnitNode:20"
```

---

**Edit, I was failing to convert the `ID` all the way so i had `"20"`, just converted the type:**

```
Number(atob(item.id).split(':')[1])
```

Question still remains about if there are any utility tools to automagically convert data being submitted to a mutation.